# Should I move to the Indy 9 or not?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy

Should I move to the Indy 9 or not?
How can i see my current version?
Where can i get newer version of Indy?

Comment: Be aware that upgrading an Indy version is not just downloading a new package, install it then run. You'll certainly have to modify your code, since every Indy major version change comes with some backward compatibility breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only change versions if you are currently facing problems that the newer version would resolve.

Answer (score 3):

Try on the [Indy project site](http://www.indyproject.org/index.de.aspx)

Comment: How can I know my current version? Thanks for site!

Comment: @robrok are you having problems with the version you currently use?

Comment: No, I just want to program easily. Roberts

Comment: well in the installation folder under ..Borland\Delphi7\Source\Indy there is a file called IdVers.inc which includes the version number

Comment: @robrok why change if you aren't facing problems? Changing creates work and risks introducing bugs.

Comment: Uuuuu, I have 9.00.10 :). OK i will not change!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still using Indy 8 and consider an upgrade, I recommend to move directly to Indy 10, which supports Delphi 5 to XE.

In Indy 10, the version is in a file IdVers.inc in the System directory. In Indy 8/9 the version is in the file IdGlobal, for example in Delphi 6:

```
gsIdVersion = '8.0.25';
```

Comment: You can also right-click on any Indy component in the Form Designer to see the installed version.